# Why fasting prayer?

Tags: faith, christian-living, science, belief

I want to know what is fasting prayer and why we want to do the fasting prayer. What does the Bible say about this?

Comment: @ Mawia I am asking what bible tell about fasting prayer, u please ignore the denominations

Comment: So your question is, *"why fast?"* - as in - "how does it help prayer?", right?

Comment: @Deeky If you just want a list of Bible verses then you might be better off with a keyword search. The more detailed answers people provide here involve some interpretation and thus require some denominational viewpoint.

Comment: @Deekey Why are you tagging it with [science] tag? It's a bit odd to me (no offence) :)

Comment: @ David Stratton How do those answers you cited answer this question which asks about the effect of fasting on prayer? Those answers do not seem to refer to the basic question of what is fasting prayer. Not trying to argue just don't understand.

Comment: @CecilBeckum - Sorry, I didn't understand that you were looking for the effect of fasting prayer.  I understood "Why we do it" and "What does the Bible say about it" to be "What is the Biblical basis that gives us motive to fast and pray".  Not what you meant.  But the answers on "[what is the importance of fasting](What's the importance of Fasting?)" do seem to answer what the effect is and what the reason is.

Answer (score 2):

Fasting prayer is thought be more sincere than just praying by some Christians.

That belief is based on the following excerpt from the book of Matthew, this particular saying of Jesus is not included in any other Gospel.

Matthew 17:15 through 21 NRKJV

> 15  Lord, have mercy on my son: for he is lunatick, and sore vexed: for ofttimes he falleth into the fire, and oft into the water.
>
> 16  And I brought him to thy disciples, and they could not cure him.
>
> 17  Then Jesus answered and said, O faithless and perverse generation, how long shall I be with you? how long shall I suffer you? bring him hither to me.
>
> 18  And Jesus rebuked the devil; and he departed out of him: and the child was cured from that very hour.
>
> 19  Then came the disciples to Jesus apart, and said, Why could not we cast him out?
>
> 20  And Jesus said unto them, Because of your unbelief: for verily I say unto you, If ye have faith as a grain of mustard seed, ye shall say unto this mountain, Remove hence to yonder place; and it shall remove; and nothing shall be impossible unto you.
>
> 21  Howbeit this kind goeth not out but **by prayer and fasting**.

Comment: Highlighting important words is very important.

Comment: @ Mawai Thank you I'll remember that for the future.